# Make a N x N grid with # symbol

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So, I just enrolled into a competition (Code Quest, Fl) and I am fairly amateur at programming(Started a year ago with Javascript), and I was looking at last year's competition questions, and since I have never had a good understanding of arrays I decided to try the challenge I put in the title. My code works fine, but in order to output the grid, I need to call to a pre-existing string inside the array, i.e. I can only call up to poundArry[3] right now because I only have 4 strings in the array. I need to know how to add a string with the number of "#" symbols as you type in the console. Sorry for any confusion in my code and any weird variable names.

```
static int gridSize;
static String pound = "#";  
static String[] poundArry = {"#","##","###","####"};
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void drawSymbols() {
    for(int i = 0; i<=gridSize;
            i++,
            System.out.println(poundArry[gridSize])
        );
}
public static void calculateGrid() {
    drawSymbols();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter Grid Size");
    gridSize = sc.nextInt()-1;
    calculateGrid();
}
```

Comment: are you trying to print a specific pattern or a grid?

Comment: Just a N x N grid

Comment: try using nested loops in that case. Try and comeback

Comment: I actually just fixed it using a command to repeat the string instead of accessing an array.
System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(gridSize, pound)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most optimal (performance/memory) way to create a `String` of repeated characters is:

```
public static String repeat(char ch, int count) {
    char[] buf = new char[count];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(buf, ch);
    return new String(buf);
}
```

If you're working on a bigger project, put that in a utility class, e.g. named `StringUtils`.

Of course, you don't actually have to write it, because it already exists in [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) third-party library: [`StringUtils.repeat(char ch, int repeat)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat-char-int-).

Or [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Strings.repeat(String string, int count)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#repeat-java.lang.String-int-).